# How can I calculate the sum of the two matrices have not the same size?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have 2 matrices ;
size A is 256x256 and  B  is 32x32 ;
How can I calculate the sum of the two matrices have not the same size ?
please help me .

Comment: What kind of result do you want? Can you show an example for two small matrices? Given you've used the image-processing tag, are these matrices images?

Comment: these are the matrices of Image .

Comment: You need to first _define_ what you mean by " sum of two matrices that don't have the same size"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with two options, if you have a 32x32 matrix `image1`, and a 256x256 matrix `image2`, you could do either `imresize(image1,size(image2))+image2` or `kron(image1,ones(8))` (because `256/32=8`).

The `imresize` method does interpolation and has no requirements on the size of the matrices, but the `kron` method requires that the size of the matrices are integer multiples of each other, so 32 and 256 is fine, but 32 and 300 wouln't be.

Here is my first (32x32) image
[image]
and here is my 256x256 image
[image]
then here is `imresize(image1,size(image2))`
[image]
and here is `imresize(image1,size(image2))+image2`
[image]
here is `kron(image1,ones(8))`
[image]
and here is `kron(image1,ones(8))+image2`
[image]

Comment: thanks David,i have another question.in my first question,Assume that 'image2' is a host image and 'image1' is a Watermark with size 32x32 in embedding Watermark stage.I used your answer.Now,Is the way that i can extract the main Watermark(image1) with the first same Watermark size 32x32 and the same quality.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. It's probably best to ask a new question and include extra detail.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you define the sum. The usual definition of matrix addition, in which corresponding entries are added together, is only defined for matrices of the same size. The [Wikipedia article on matrix addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition) mentions two additional types of addition:

- The direct sum merely embeds the two operands on the diagonal of a new matrix, in your case creating a 288 x 288 matrix.
- The Kronecker sum is essentially a block matrix consisting of multiples of B formed from individual elements of A using scalar multiplication.

Comment: the result of sum have to 256x256 .

Comment: Like I said, normal matrix addition simply is not defined for matrices of different sizes. I'm not aware of any other definitions that will produce a 256x256 matrix from your inputs. Maybe you simply want to pad B with zeroes so that it is the same size as A, but without an explanation of how you intend to interpret the sum, there's no reason to believe any addition you come up with will be useful.